# Ideal class groups of real abelian number fields

Tags: nt.number-theory

I have a question from page 13 of Thaine's article on Ideal class groups of real abelian number fields - Annals of Math, 128 (1988).

Here's an attempt to summarize.

Let $W = E/C$ where $E$ is the group of units of $K$ - a real abelian number field and $C$ is a subgroup of circular units. Let $\Delta = Gal (K/\mathbb{Q})$ and $\chi : \Delta \rightarrow \mathbb{Z}_p^*$ be a non-trivial Dirichlet character and $e_{\chi} = (1/ \mid \Delta \mid) \sum_{\sigma \in \Delta} \chi(\sigma) \sigma^{-1} $ be the corresponding idempotent and $p^a$ the exact idempotent of the $\chi$-component $e_{\chi} (W)_p$ of $W_p$ ($W_p$ is the $p$-Sylow subgroup of $W$). Since $e_{\chi} (W)_p \cong e_{\chi} (E/E^{p^k}C)_p \cong e_{\chi} (E/E^{p^k})/e_{\chi} (E^{p^k}C/E^{p^k})$, so the elements $\eta \in E$ such that $\eta C \in e_{\chi} (W)_p$ are the same as elements $\eta \in E$ such that $\eta E^{p^k} \in e_{\chi} (E/E^{p^k})$

Question:

Why is it that for such elements $\eta$, we have $\sigma (\eta) \equiv \eta^{\chi(\sigma)} \mod E^{p^k}$?

Comment: For $\eta \in \mathbb{Z}_p[E]$, $\sigma( e_\chi (\eta )) = \chi(\sigma) e_\chi (\eta )$ ?

Comment: I don't think I understand. Are you asking me or suggesting an answer?

Comment: Let $\mathbb{Z}/(p^k)[E/E^{p^k}]$ the group ring. Then for $a \in \mathbb{Z}/(p^k)[E/E^{p^k}], \sigma( e_\chi (a )) = \chi(\sigma) e_\chi (a )$. Let the surjective group morphism $\phi : \mathbb{Z}/(p^k)[E/E^{p^k}] \to E/E^{p^k}, \chi(\sum_n a_n g_n) = \prod_n g_n^{a_n}$. Then $\sigma ( \phi(a)) = \phi( \sigma(a)) $ and $\sigma ( \phi(e_\chi(a))) = \phi( \sigma ( e_\chi(a)))= \phi ( \chi(\sigma) e_\chi(a))= (\phi (e_\chi(a)))^{\chi(\sigma)}$ where $\phi(e_\chi(\mathbb{Z}/(p^k)[E/E^{p^k}]))$ is your $\chi$-component